# How to add/create/draw line between md-radio-buttons inside div with label Angular Materials

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material, material-design

I want to add lines between md-radio-buttons for component with dynamic data.

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="selected"  layout="row">
  <div ng-repeat="i in items">
    <label>{{i.name}}</label>
  <md-radio-button  value="{{i}}"></md-radio-button>
  </div>
</md-radio-group>
```

It should draw a line between every two buttons. Lines length should be set as a minimum distance between but it could be automatically increased if needed

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKyjbx)

Comment: Please try and have a full description of what you want in advance.
It seems like you didn't describe the problem clear enough, even in your second and third edit. `also when i centered buttons it is drawed in wrong place.` how can someone understand from that what you want? share some code, tell us where you want to position the buttons and what are those buttons. Are they the circles? or something you try to position underneath them? please edit your question as one coherent question. The "steps" are irrelevant if you change the terminology between them.

Comment: When someone give me minus should write what am I doing wrong and I will try to fix it or avoid it next time, other way (in my opinion) is pointless.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to do in my previous comment.

Comment: Since you wanted a more precise description of the problems I have with this question: 1. not clear enough. Sounds like a collection of thoughts 2. as it is now, your question is a dialog with a specific answer. This makes your question hard to read and dependent on a specific answer (which another user might decide to remove or what not). 3. Editing questions is very important to make them clearer. But try and edit the actual question if it wasn't defined properly on the first try. Right now, when I read your question, non of the **Edits** are easily understood.

Comment: It should be better now. Thanks for your time. Straight to the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added

```
class="{{$last ? 'last' : '' }}"
```

to the

```
md-radio-button
```

directive, 
and

```
<div class="line"></div>
```

inside it.

now all we have to do is add this css code to your stylesheet:

```
.line {
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 52px;
    background: grey;
    left: -11px;
    top: -2px;
 }

 .last .line {
      display: none;
 }
```

## Edit

I fixed my example to match your new dynamic requirement
please see [This CodePen](http://codepen.io/ortichon/pen/NNPYbG)
what I did is to add two "line" divs, before and after.
each line is 50% of the container div width, so together they cover it's entire width.
the first and last divs in the ng-repeat are treated differently -> first won't show the "before" line, and last won't show the "after"

hope it solves your problem

Comment: He meant that as a "before\after" example. Good answer! example and all that bling

Comment: exactly Thatkookooguy

Comment: Edit, when i used it for different data set it crashes.